# TreeView - clicar no Node e abrir tela especificia

Tags: c#, treeview

Tenho um `TreeView`, com alguns itens de configurações:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Gostaria de ao clicar duas vezes em um `node` ele abra um form especifico, o evento de clicar duas vezes e abrir o form, está OK, o problema é como eu distinguo um `node` do outro?

Exemplo, ao clicar duas vezes em *Usuários* ele abre a *tela Usuários*, ao clicar duas vezes em *Permissões* ele abre a *tela de Permissões*.

Evento `DoubleClick`:

```
this.treeView1.NodeMouseDoubleClick += 
new System.Windows.Forms.TreeNodeMouseClickEventHandler(this.TreeView1_doubleClick);
```

Metodo que estou utilizando para gerar o `doubleclick`:

```
private void TreeView1_doubleClick(Object sender, TreeNodeMouseClickEventArgs e)// clicar em usuarios     
{
     Manutencao_usuarios clickmu = new Manutencao_usuarios();
     clickmu.ShowDialog();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode fazer isso no evento [`NodeMouseDoubleClick`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.windows.forms.treeview.nodemousedoubleclick(v=vs.110).aspx) do `TreeView`:

```
private void treeView1_NodeMouseDoubleClick(object sender, TreeNodeMouseClickEventArgs e)
{
    string node = e.Node.Text;
    switch (node)
    {
        case "Servidores e Diretórios":
            // Abrir o formulário Servidores e Diretórios
            break;
        case "Usuários":
            // Abrir o formulário Usuários
            break;

        // Restante do código...

        default:
            // Fazer algo se nenhuma das opções acima for clicada
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Perfeito, Muito obrigado